# Calendar Day Render event

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I have created a booking app which shows the available and not available date by C# asp.net,
when i debug the app locally it works fine, but when i upload it on the remote server it gives HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found, recently i came to know that the issue come from calender day render event, if i remove the code my app work on the remote server.

```
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row1 in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string dt1;

            DateTime dm1;



            if (row1.Cells[2].Text.Equals("1"))
            {
                dt1 = row1.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
                dm1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1);
                if (e.Day.Date.Equals(dm1))
                {
                    e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />availble"));
                    //e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.;
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
                    e.Cell.Enabled = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Very strange. HTTP 404 error generally related with file missing or URL issue. How come your calendar render event is to do anything with 404?

Comment: it makes me really confused!!

Answer (score 0):

The DayRender event requires the event-handler to be mapped. You haven't shown that in your code. You'll need to add this during your Page_Init event (not the Page constructor):

public override void OnInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) { this.Calendar1.DayRender += new EventHandler( Calendar1_DayRender ); }

Comment: thanks Patrik
but how i will implement this code, it gives me this error:
No overload for 'Calendar1_DayRender' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Try with below code and if still getting same error then send me more information with your aspx page

    Calendar1.DayRender += new DayRenderEventHandler(this.DayRender);